# I want to take only particular value from returned JSON result

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json

I want to take message value, which is under message array and parameter name equal to documentId.(which is bold in bellow code)
bellow code which i have tried but not working as described above.
`dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonDATA);
var recid = obj.messages.message;`

**JSON Data**

```
{
  "message": "Success",
  "messages": [
    {
      "parameter": "documentId",
      "message": "8111ffb4-dddc-4d94-b050-bf8fa050181f"
    },
    {
      "parameter": "refNo",
      "message": "INNT19/75254854"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please Help me to take the particular value only in C#.

Comment: `obj.messages` is an array, you need to access either its first or second element first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the message at the correct index in the messages-array:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonDATA);
var recid = obj.messages[0].message;
```

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar hehe, yeah that was close :D

Answer (score 1):

As `messages` is an array in your JSON, If you need to read any property of perticular element of an array then you need to use **index**. Something like

```
var recid = obj.messages[0].message;
```